# registration plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, user-roles, membership

I am working on a website and need the fallowing functionality:

**From the admin area, I need to be able to add/remove/edit codes/tokens that I will later send out to people so they can come to my site and use them to register a user.**

I just do not want people to be able to register to my site without a code that I will give to them before hand. Does that make sense?

I do not want people that I do not know to be able to register(people that does not have one of the preset codes), but at the same time I would like to automate it so they do not have to wait on me to create a user name for them.

EDIT: I hope that this improved my question.

For example:

I go to my admin page and add a new code "meeting20120505". After I have this code already in the database I can go to a meeting and if I meet someone there that he is interested in my website and would like to register I will give him this new code I just made(meeting20120505) and with it the person could go to my website and register.
The registration could go in two ways:

1. I will give him a link to a for that has one field that he will enter the code and if the code he matches the codes in my database he will be redirected to a registration page.

2. On my registration page I have a field that is required and will be validated and id there is no match he will not be able to register.

**Please if you are going to mark me down at least share with me why! 
Thanks.**

Comment: Please improve your question: What have you tried already? What kind of tokens do you need? Where exactly do you want to set them?

Comment: There is no question here. Please avoid questions that are *[overly complex and specific things (known as work for me for free)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq)*

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34464/registration-key

Comment: I guess it could be. I just did not know that the term is registration key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several plugins around that allow you to customize your registration process.  One such plugin is called [Pie Register](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pie-register/).

Among the many features it offers, it allows:

> **Invitation Codes** Is your blog super exclusive? If so, you better require an invite to join your high end crew. Setup multiple codes and track where your new users are coming from with the optional Invitation Tracking Dashboard Widget.

You can set up as many invitation codes as you want from the admin interface.  Users will need to enter one of these codes on the registration form to continue.